# How to change a column type from integer to biginteger while other tables have foreign id relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to change a column (admin_campaigns table) from integer to big integer by adding this:

```
 $table->bigInteger('category_id')->change();
```

But it says,
Cannot change column 'category_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'admin_campaigns_
category_id_foreign'")

How can I solve this?

**admin_campaigns table:**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('title',50);
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')->on('admin_campaign_categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->tinyInteger('is_used_multimedia')->default(1)->comment('1 = yes and 0 = no');

            $table->timestamps();


        });
    }
```

**New migration:**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->change();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the `category_id` from int to bigint, you would need to:

1. Drop the foreign key on the `category_id` column: `$table->dropForeign('admin_campaigns_category_id_foreign');`
2. Change the `category_id` column to bigint: `$table->bigInteger('category_id')->change();`
3. Before being able to re-establish the foreign key, you need to change the `admin_campaign_categories.id` column to bigint too:

   ```
     Schema::table('admin_campaign_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id')->change();
     });
   ```

Before you can do that, you obviously need to do steps 1 and 2 on all other columns in all other tables that have foreign keys on `admin_campaign_categories.id`.

So if the `admin_campaigns` table was the only table referencing `admin_campaign_categories.id`, you can do:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('admin_campaigns_category_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::table('admin_campaign_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigInteger('id')->change();
    });

    Schema::table('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->change();
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')->on('admin_campaign_categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('admin_campaigns_category_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::table('admin_campaign_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->change();
    });

    Schema::table('admin_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->change();
        $table->foreign('category_id')
              ->references('id')->on('admin_campaign_categories')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

---

#### A Word on Primary Key Columns

I also want to emphasize that you should never use signed integer / signed big integer types for numeric primary key columns. Instead, you should use

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->change();
```

everywhere in the migration above.

The reason for this is that a numeric primary key will probably never be set to a negative value, which holds true especially when using it as an auto increment column.

By setting the column to `integer` or `bigInteger` types, you limit the maximum assignable value to 2,147,483,647 or 2<sup>63</sup>-1, respectively, whereas you could save a value twice as high when using `unsignedInteger` or `unsignedBigInteger` types, with the same amount of storage needed (4/8 bytes).

In most scenarios, both ranges are so high that you will probably never notice a difference, but it's basically a waste of resources. I have seen an integer id exceed the maximum range once in a user table for a very busy application, and it's not pretty. Basically, in MySQL the whole DB just stops working completely.

Comment: Can you please tell what I should add in down function?

Comment: public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('update_table_admin_campaigns_change_category_id');
    }

Comment: No, no... dropIfExists drops a table if it exists, not a migration. In the down migration, you reverse the steps you do in the up migration in reverse order. I'll add the down migration to the answer. You don't NEED a down migration, however, and on live DBs, you would probably never execute it in a real life scenario.

Comment: after adding down function you provided, it throws the following error again while migration rollback.  Cannot change column 'category_id': used in a foreign key constra
int 'admin_campaigns_category_id_foreign

Comment: Oh, yeah... it doesn't drop the foreign key before changing the category_id to integer. I edited the code. Try again please.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, if you have a lot of keys to change, we've developed a package to automate this:

https://github.com/AXN-Informatique/laravel-pk-int-to-bigint